# one image animate translateX react naitve and repeat

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

how to animate translateX react naitve and in finite repeat like this image

[image: animate translateX react naitve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with css and styled-components props

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
background-position-x: ${props => props.positionPercentage};
```